# Git and Red Hat Open Shift

Tags: git, clone

For RedHat Openshift it has the following instruction for a clone to your local host:
git clone ssh://12272296@jimX-jimsapps.rhcloud.com/~/git/jimX.git/

What I want to do is create a folder in c:/xampp/htdocs/rhos   (on my local host)

So I try: (with a command prompt open and sitting at C:)
git clone ssh://12272296@jimX-jimsapps.rhcloud.com/~/git/xampp/htdocs/rhos.git/

And I get an error:
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Inva

Do you have to clone into something of the form jimX on your local machine?

What would be the command to clone into c:/xampp/htdocs/rhos ?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

The [Git FAQ mentions](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#protocol_error%3a_bad_line_length_character):

> It likely means you have some extraneous characters, info message or something upon logging into ssh in command mode.

To test this, do:

```
ssh ssh://12272296@jimX-jimsapps.rhcloud.com echo testing commands
```

> You should only see `testing commands` returned.
>   If there are any other characters, you should examine your dot shell rc file to find any echo or other commands that may produce output.

That was the conclusion as well of this [blog post](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/node/303):

> Ahh! This was the information I needed to solve the problem.
>   In my case the problem was actually that I had an '`echo`' in my `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, which affected the protocol.
>   Removing the echo fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. The problem is that the shell you get assigned, oo-trap-user does the following check:

```
# replace leading tilde (~) with user's home path
realpath = os.path.expanduser(thearg)
if not realpath.startswith(config['GEAR_BASE_DIR']):
    syslog.syslog("Invalid repository: not in openshift_root (%s) - %s: (%s)" %
                  (config['GEAR_BASE_DIR'], thearg, realpath))
    print "Invalid repository %s: not in application root" % thearg
    sys.exit(3)
```

So the git repository has to be in the GEAR_BASE_DIR which leaves you only with your home directory.

To debug, do smth like `ssh yourmachine git-receive-pack /path/to/your/location`

Answer (score 0):

One of the key issues here is the Git config file, for the project in question; the problem is that this file cannot be read correctly to retrieve the necessary information for connecting to your repository.

You should ensure that there is only one parameter per line, and no stray characters or spaces. If you did find such errors in the config file then this fix should help to alleviate the problem and allow you to once again access the repository.